# Compilation of derived class from boost::spirit::qi::grammar failed with __declspec( dllexport )

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to implement a class that inherits from boost::spirit::qi::grammar and make it exportable in dynamic library:

```
#pragma once
#include <impexp.h>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

using boost::spirit::ascii::space_type;
struct EXPORT_DLLCLASS Grammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar< char const*, space_type >
{
   Grammar()
       : Grammar::base_type( expr )
   {
   }
   boost::spirit::qi::rule< char const*, space_type > expr, term;
};
```

I'm using `EXPORT_DLLCLASS` to specify `__attribute__( ( visibility( "default" ) ) )` or `__declspec( dllexport )` depending on the platform. Build succeeds under Linux platform, but I have problems with compilation under Windows platform with the following errors:

```
C:\.conan\oq2odq\1\include\boost/proto/extends.hpp(536,17):  error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<const char *, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0>, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type> > >, 0>'
              : proto_expr_()
                ^
C:\.conan\oq2odq\1\include\boost/proto/proto_fwd.hpp(377,16):  note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::proto::exprns_::extends<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<const char *, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0>, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type> > >, 0>, boost::spirit::qi::grammar<const char *, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0>, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type>, boost::proto::domainns_::default_domain, 0>::extends' requested here
        struct extends;
               ^
C:\.conan\oq2odq\1\include\boost/proto/detail/preprocessed/expr_variadic.hpp(50,49):  note: default constructor of 'expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<const char *, boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0>, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type> > >, 0>' is implicitly deleted because field 'child0' has no default constructor
        typedef Arg0 proto_child0; proto_child0 child0;
```

Build succeeds if `EXPORT_DLLCLASS` is not specified.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed, see it side-by-side with MSVC 19.34.31931 x64 (and GCC) although with slightly different diagnostics on https://compiler-explorer.com/z/o67TYxdnf:

```
C:/data/libraries/installed/x64-windows/include\boost/proto/extends.hpp(558): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'T *' to 'boost::proto::detail::not_a_valid_type'
        with
        [
            T=const boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<const char *,boost::spirit::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type>>
        ]
C:/data/libraries/installed/x64-windows/include\boost/proto/extends.hpp(558): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
C:/data/libraries/installed/x64-windows/include\boost/proto/extends.hpp(558): note: while compiling class template member function 'boost::proto::exprns_::extends<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<T>,0>,boost::spirit::qi::grammar<const char *,boost::spirit::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type>,boost::proto::domainns_::default_domain,0>::operator boost::proto::detail::not_a_valid_type(void) const'
        with
        [
            T=boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<const char *,boost::spirit::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type>>
        ]
C:/data/libraries/installed/x64-windows/include\boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/grammar.hpp(32): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::proto::exprns_::extends<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<T>,0>,boost::spirit::qi::grammar<const char *,boost::spirit::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type>,boost::proto::domainns_::default_domain,0>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<const char *,boost::spirit::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type>>
        ]
<source>(6): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::qi::grammar<const char *,boost::spirit::ascii::space_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type,boost::spirit::unused_type>' being compiled
Compiler returned: 2
```

I think this is likely a compiler issue. I'd report it with the Boost Proto maintainers: https://github.com/boostorg/proto/issues to see whether they can confirm or suggest a workaround

Comment: They don't seem to respond very quickly. There are opened issues since 2018...

Comment: @t_watcher not filing guarantees that no one will respond, even though they might have a 10 second reply...